# how to move the custom block middle of the page in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, blocks, xml, cms-block, home-page

> I added custom block in home page Magento 2, but it's showing in the top of the page
>
> **I want to move to after banners**

how can I achieve this?

[image]
*cms_index_index.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="FM\Quick\Block\Custom" name="default_home_page" template="FM_Quick::cms.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: How do you managing the banners?....Are you using any extension?

Comment: no bro.........

Comment: Then how the banner is displaying?

Comment: it's just image bro......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call your custom phtml file after the banner image using

```
{{block class="FM\Quick\Block\Custom" name="default_home_page" template="FM_Quick::cms.phtml"}}
```

Comment: Element with ID 'default_home_page' already exists.

Comment: remove your code from cms_index_index.xml